# How do I sync a directory from Mac to iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, data-synchronization, data-transfer, ipados

How do I sync directory `~/to-sync` from Mac to iPad through network or a USB type-C cable?

Is there some handy tools like `rsync` or `adb-sync` (for Android devices) to do that? I prefer FOSS tools. :)

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running? Are you using iCloud Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive or similar?

Comment: @nohillside 10.15.7 19H2, the latest stable version.